# Javascript Push not working on Key Value pairs

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to add a key value pair to array called **dataxx** such as {x:1,y:2},{x:2,y:3} etc. However when I try **dataxx.push** it doesnt seem to be working - any ideas why or how else I can push to the array?

```
var dataxx= [{x: 0, y: 0}];

    $( document).ready(function (){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: true,
            jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod",
            error: function(){
                alert( 'Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed' );
            },
            success: function(data){

                for (i in data)
                {
                    dataxx.push({x: 4, y: 5});
                    //$( "#postlist" ).append(data[i].id);
                }   

                //alert(dataxx);


            }});
    });
```

Comment: It should work. Try `console.log(data);` in `success` handler. What is its value?

Comment: How do you know its not working? Did you log it outside ajax request?

Comment: When I look in console it outputs: 0: Object
$$hashKey: "object:11"
series: 0
x: 0
y: 0
__proto__: Object
1: Object
x: 4
y: 5
__proto__: Object
2: Object
x: 4
y: 5
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: But I would like it to output [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x:1,y:1}]; Because I am using the array inside a chart script that accepts this data format

Comment: That's just the way the console displays all the properties of an object. The actual data is what you pushed. If you want to see it in that simpler format, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataxx))`

Answer (score 1):

i have just add one line of code to see object your code is working fine

```
var dataxx= [{x: 0, y: 0}];

$( document).ready(function (){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://demo8162910.mockable.io/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: true,
        jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod",
        error: function(){
            alert( 'Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed' );
        },
        success: function(data){

            for (i in data)
            {
                dataxx.push({x: 4, y: 5});
                //$( "#postlist" ).append(data[i].id);
            }   

            console.log(dataxx);/*object is here */


        }});
});
```

Comment: I would like it to output [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x:1,y:1}]; Because I am using the array inside a chart script that accepts this data format. But in the console it outputs:

Comment: 0: Object $$hashKey: "object:11" series: 0 x: 0 y: 0 proto: Object 1: Object x: 4 y: 5 proto: Object 2: Object x: 4 y: 5 proto: Object length: 3 proto: Array[0]